# Array too big for division in matlab but not python

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, matrix, fft

The problem I have is array too big in Matlab. The array data comes from audio file. I want to get the impulse response.

I first FFT the original and recorded audio. Then the division of recorded by original. Lastly inverse FFT to get the impulse response. That was what I planned to do but I got stuck at the division part.

Stuck using Matlab, I found a [python code](https://github.com/josephernest/impulseresponse.py) that can do it just fine. I rewrite the code into Matlab and the problem is back again. The code is incomplete but it is enough to show the problem.

Hope to get many advice and criticism. Thanks

**Planned to do but failed so moved on to the next code**

```
[y_sweep,Fs] = audioread('sweep.wav');
[y_rec,Fs] = audioread('edit_rec_sweep_laptop_1.2.wav');
fft_y1 = abs(fft(y_rec(:,1)));
fft_y2 = abs(fft(y_rec(:,2)));
fft_x = abs(fft(y_sweep));
fft_h1 = fft_y1/fft_x;
% fft_h2 = fft_y2/fft_x;
% fft_h = [fft_h1,fft_h2];
% h1 = ifft(fft1_h);
```

**'Translated' code from python but still failed thus came here**

```
[a,fs] = audioread('sweep.wav'); % sweep
[b,fs] = audioread('rec.wav'); % rec

a = pad(a,fs*50,fs*10);
b = pad(b,fs*50,fs*10);
[m,n] = size(b);
h = zeros(m,n); 

for chan = 1:2
    b1 = b(:,1);
    ffta = abs(fft(a));
    fftb = abs(fft(b1));
    ffth = fftb / ffta;
end
```

**pad.m function (translated from python but should be correct)**

```
function y = pad(data, t_full, t_pre)
[row_dim,col_dim] = size(data);
t_post = t_full - row_dim - t_pre;
if t_post > 0
    if col_dim == 1
        y = [zeros(t_pre,1);data;zeros(t_post,1)];
%         width = [t_pre,t_post];
    else
        y1 = [zeros(t_pre,1);data(:,1);zeros(t_post,1)];
        y2 = [zeros(t_pre,1);data(:,2);zeros(t_post,1)];
        y = [y1,y2];
%         width = [[t_pre,t_post],[0,0]];
    end 
else
    if col_dim == 1
        y = [zeros(t_pre,1);data(t_full - t_pre:end,1)];
%         width = [t_pre,0];
    else
        y = [zeros(t_pre,1);data(t_full - t_pre:end,1)];
%         width = [[t_pre,0],[0,0]];
    end
end

end
```

**Error**

```
Error using  \ 
Requested 4800000x4800000 (171661.4GB) array exceeds
maximum array size preference. Creation of arrays
greater than this limit may take a long time and
cause MATLAB to become unresponsive. See array size
limit or preference panel for more information.

Error in impulseresponse (line 13)
    ffth = fftb / ffta;
```

Comment: Do you want element-wise (`./`) division? (hint: yes, yes you do)

Comment: @AnderBiguri i love that hint of yours lol. the code is up and running. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The forward slash is shorthand in MATLAB for [**`mrdivide()`**](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html). **This is for solving systems of linear matrix equations**. What I think you want is [`rdivide`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rdivide.html) which is denoted by `./`.

- `c = a/b` is only equivalent to standard division if `b` is scalar.
- `c = a./b` is element-wise division, where every element of `a` is divided by the corresponding element of `b`.

  ```
  [1 2 3] ./ [2 4 9]
  >> ans = [0.5, 0.5, 0.3333]
  ```

So the last active line of your "planned to do" code becomes

```
fft_h1 = fft_y1 ./ fft_x;
```

Comment: thank you. the code functions now. but is it mathematically correct? as in division for fourier transform. i browsed through one website stating that there is no division for matrix. it only work by inversing the matrix like A*A^-1. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: That's a very broad mathematical question,  which is one of the first things to understand when learning about linear algebra. Please ask maths questions on math.stackoverflow.com or ask another specific algorithm question here, thanks